# YA Book about a Banshee

Tags: story-identification, books, folklore

When I was in middle school ( 2012ish?), I read a book that had a young girl as the main character. The young girl had come from a line of banshees. She screams when she is by someone who will die/maybe gets a vision of the death (I do not remember exactly). There is also her love interest, this guy who claims to be the male version of a banshee, instead of hearing the banshee shriek as ear-piercing, he hears it as a sweet melody, like a siren song calling him to her.  That is all I remember of this book and I really want to reread it. Can anyone help?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Possibly *[My Soul to Take](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6315602-my-soul-to-take)* (2009) by Rachel Vincent, first book of the *Soul Screamers* series.

[image: Front cover of My Soul to Take]

> She doesn't see dead people. She senses when someone near her is about to die. And when that happens, a force beyond her control compels her to scream bloody murder. Literally.
>
> Kaylee just wants to enjoy having caught the attention of the hottest guy in school. But a normal date is hard to come by when Nash seems to know more about her need to scream than she does. And when classmates start dropping dead for no apparent reason, only Kaylee knows who'll be next.

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1609853229?book_show_action=true) mentions that Nash is a male bean sidhe:

> The concept is unique. It deals with death, souls and bean sidhe. Kaylee knows when someone is going to die when she screams. She predicts death yet she can't stop it. Her screams are ear spitting to humans but music to male bean sidhe. That's when she meets Nash who completely understands her for who she is.

Found with a search for `site:goodreads.com "young adult" banshee`